# Sitemap (XML) - sub routes

Tags: xml, sitemap

I have browsed many pages on how to write XML sitemaps but none of them describe how to add sub routes to the main routes.

So if I have a route '/articles', I can add it (in a laravel blade template):

```
<url>
    <loc>{{ url('/articles') }}</loc>
</url>
```

Then there are routes to each article, for example `'/articles/5'`.
So I how/where do I add those routes? Info seems non existant on the web.
Should I do:

```
 <url>
      <loc>{{ url('/articles') }}</loc>

        <url>
           <loc>{{ url('/articles/4') }}</loc>
           <loc>{{ url('/articles/12') }}</loc>
           <loc>{{ url('/articles/2') }}</loc>
       </url>

 </url>
```

This is probably wrong. My idea is also to be able to import this XML file and display it as html with css on a page.